Does Occam's Razor favor metaphysical solipsism?
From Wikipedia:

In metaphysics, Metaphysical solipsism is the variety of idealism which asserts that nothing exists externally to this one mind, and since this mind is the whole of reality then the "external world" was never anything more than an idea. It can also be expressed by the assertion "there is nothing external to these present experiences", in other words, no reality exists beyond whatever is presently being cognized by that one mind. The aforementioned definition of solipsism entails the non-existence of anything presently unperceived including the external world, causation, other minds (including God's mind or a subconscious mind), the past or future, and a subject of experience. Despite their ontological non-existence, these entities may nonetheless be said to "exist" as useful descriptions of the various experiences and thoughts that constitute 'this' mind.
Metaphysical solipsism differs from Epistemological solipsism in that, Metaphysical Solipsism, and therefore one adhering to it as a position, states that nothing exists externally to this one mind, while Epistemological Solipsism, states that nothing can be known for certain to exist externally to this one mind.

Given that Occam's Razor aims to minimize the number of ontological entities one posits, and given that metaphysical solipsism requires positing only this mind as existent, does it follow that Occam's Razor favors metaphysical solipsism?

That kind of argument is enough to show that the "razor" is a sort of metaphor and not a rule of method.

We prefer the theory/explanation that posits less "abstract entities"... provided that is the true one.

@KristianBerry “Why can't my mind bend reality to its whims, regardless of the question of theoretical elegance?” Why can’t the world behave randomly regardless of the question of theoretical elegance? (It seems to follow laws)

Yes, Occam's Razor taken with no other limiting principle leads directly to metaphysical solipsism.
It is undoubtable that the conception of the universe that I hold in my mind is less complex than the real universe, if the real universe exists. Therefore, if I want to take the simplest explanation for all the phenomena that I observe, it is simplest ontologically to suppose that there is nothing at all beyond what I directly observe: my own sensory perceptions at the present moment, and my thoughts.
Even to suppose that these have a pattern, much less to ask what that pattern might be, requires adding extra ontological assumptions: We must introduce a category of things such as "laws of physics" or "patterns" and then we can fill it in to explain what I see. Granting this for a moment, the solipsist loses no ground in his argument by declaring: They have a pattern simply because I imagine that they do.
It is natural to point out that solipsism lacks the explanatory power of other theories: After all, solipsism can't explain why you observe X and not Y. However, this is not fair to the solipsist, as the attack assumes a priori that there is something to explain.
As an analogy, suppose we ask an atheist some question in Christian theology, e.g. the mode of Christ's presence in Communion. The atheist cannot explain how Christ is present in the bread and the wine, but a Lutheran, an Anglican, and a Catholic can. Does that mean atheism has less explanatory power than any of these Christian sects? Obviously, that would be unfair. The atheist denies that there is anything there that needs explanation; there's no need to explain how Christ can be present in the communion elements because he isn't present in them.
Likewise, the solipsist has no responsibility to explain phenomena whose existence he denies. For example, you might accuse solipsism of lacking predictive power about future events, but the solipsist does not accept the premise that there are future events to predict.

Let me go into a bit more detail on the application of Occam's razor:
If it is necessary to answer questions of the form "why is X true instead of Y?" then every worldview must face a brick wall at the end of the chain, i.e.

Why is X1 true?
X1 is true because X2 is true.
Why is X2 true?
X2 is true because X3 is true.
Etc.

Obviously, if we don't want to get caught in a loop, we cannot answer every demand for an explanation. (Note: of course each step Xk might be a complex statement containing many claims, in which case X(k+1) should explain all of those claims.) Let's say we stop at n, i.e. "Because Xn is true" and that's the step we leave unexplained. All the Xk for k<n are explained in terms of Xn, so that forms the basis of our whole explanatory system. All things are explained in terms of Xn. Xn is the set of all brute facts.
Occam's razor suggests two or three non-equivalent ways to evaluate a given chain of explanations. Firstly, we ought to have the simplest possible Xn to explain our X1. Secondly, we would ideally have n as small as possible. Thirdly, we would like to have some handle on what Xn actually is and the chain of logic from there to X1 (though I'm not sure that this properly falls under the umbrella of "Occam's razor", it definitely seems desirable; more on this topic at the bottom).
With this in mind, let's evaluate some possible worldviews might be:

Deterministic Naturalism: Xn is the set of physical laws plus the initial state of the universe. n might be quite large. The physical laws might be quite complex, or quite simple, we can't really tell. Modern physics suggest something rather complicated.
Nondeterministic naturalism: Similar to deterministic Naturalism, we must include in Xn the laws of physics and the universe's initial state. However, in light of random processes, we must also include the outcome of every random event as something "unexplained"; if A or B happens randomly, and B is the one that actually happened, we must add to Xn that B happened, since there was no reason for it. Thus Xn includes not just the initial state and the physical laws, but a track of the universe's history up til now.
Religious monotheism (inc. Christianity, Judaism, and Islam): All things are made by a single God. Xn is the statement defining God, n may be quite large. Most monotheists believe in some notion of divine simplicity, that is, God is not made of parts, and therefore we have hope that Xn is a relatively simple proposition. The cost of this is the complete impossibility of actually knowing Xn renders that simplicity pretty much a moot point in terms of explanatory power. Basically, even if we have Xn, we're missing X(n-1) because we don't have any idea how or why God does most or all of the things that he does. (And for the record, religious monotheists are OK with this, obviously an omniscient, omnipotent God may have reasons and methods that we can't even possibly know anything about.)
Philosophical monotheism (e.g. Platonism or Daoism): this is similar to monotheism, but "God" is an impersonal first principle which is fundamentally unknowable. These worldviews usually take as an article of faith that Xn is actually reducible to a single principle, e.g. see Dao De Jing chapter 42, which declares that everything originates from the Dao. This suffers the same problems as monotheism (see above) with more hope of Xn being a single postulate but at the cost of eliminating any hope that we can begin to know what Xn is.
Solipsism: Xn is simply the existence of my own thoughts. n=1.

So as far as n being small is concerned, obviously solipsism wins by a country mile.
Complexity of Xn: Of the two forms of naturalism, it seems like that deterministic Naturalism is simpler because then Xn doesn't need to track the history of the universe. But it's possible that a "non-deterministic physical laws + universe's history" is simpler than the simplest deterministic explanation. But, in any case, the total complexity of the universe and its physical laws seems certain to be greater than the complexity of my own thoughts. I do not even understand all the mathematical background required for quantum mechanics, and I am a mathematician! So it appears that the physical laws themselves are quite complex, and we must add to that some (probably many) statements about the initial state of the universe. It is certain at the very least that naturalism's Xn must posit the existence of more things than solipsism, as solipsism proposes only "my mind" while naturalism proposes "all the raw material of the universe (including whatever my mind is made of)". So solipsism is better than naturalism in terms of Xn's complexity.
Compared with naturalism, both forms of monotheism have the advantage that their Xn postulates (as a brute fact) the existence of only one thing. Comparing religious monotheism with solipsism, however, it is plain that God's mind ought to be in some sense "greater" and almost certainly more complex than mine, so religious monotheism's Xn is of greater complexity than that of solipsism.
Philosophical monotheism's Xn on the other hand, resists measures of complexity. It is assumed to be simple. So these worldviews may beat solipsism on the count of complexity of Xn. However, if we even speak about the Dao, the concept we have in our mind is not the true Dao, so such statements cannot be asserted with confidence. Perhaps "complexity" isn't a concept that is actually applicable to the Dao.
So, as regards complexity of Xn, philosophical monotheism might be superior to solipsism, but more likely the two are just non-comparable. Both of them beat all the other worldviews handily.
Knowability of the explanation: Here, solipsism is the clear victor again, as the entire chain of reasoning is one singular step, which is very easy to grasp, and Xn by definition contains nothing that I don't already know. The other worldviews all hang on a theoretical possibilty of following the chain of reasoning from Xn down to X1. But without the possibility of actually doing this in real life, it seems like a moot point. (Philosophical monotheism might deny even the theoretical possibility of following the chain of logic.)
As an example, suppose we ask each worldview: "why did my friend get cancer?" We all might trace this back to some proximate cause, but no one can actually follow the logic back to first principles. To say "God works in mysterious ways. We can't know why he does what he does, but we can know that he has good reasons for what he does" is no different (as an explanation) from "the universe is too complex to actually trace from the big bang until now what caused your friend to get cancer, but we can be sure that there is a chain of cause-and-effect all the way back to the beginning." Both "explanations", while categorically quite different, hinge on the same idea: theoretically, an explanation from first principles exists, but we don't have access to it, so we can't know what it is.
Thus, we can see that all worldviews except solipsism rest on the claim that "an explanation exists, but I don't know what it is". While not actually a brute fact, in terms of explanatory power, such assertions aren't much different. However, for the solipsist, all the conceivable explanations are known a fortiori and we never encounter that issue. Nothing that is unexplained is in the category of things that require explanation.
Conclusion: In terms of Occam's razor, solipsism is clearly favored over other worldviews. The reasoning used to get here applies whether we understand "simpler" in ontological or in syntactic terms. Even considering explanatory power as a factor, solipsism still comes out on top. Indeed, this is solipsism's trump card as it never needs to resort to the cop-out "an explanation exists" when none is demonstrated. Unlike all other worldviews, solipsism can actually exhibit every explanation that it claims exists.

Postscript: I have not addressed polytheistic worldviews, as I do not feel confident that I can accurately present them. It is my impression that Hinduism is actually philosophically monotheistic, i.e. all the gods are emenations (in some sense) from the fundamental divine principle Brahman. I may be mistaken about that understanding, however. In any case, I don't think polytheism of any form would fare much differently from the other non-solipsistic worldviews I assessed.
I think that the best way to refute solipsism is to resort to innate knowledge and intuition. One might also use a variant of Pascal's wager: even if solipsism is correct, there is no benefit offered from believing in it. On the other hand, if it is wrong, it seems that believing in it would be detrimental. However, this suffers the same weaknesses as the classical version of Pascal's wager.
In any case, it is clear to me that Occam's razor as the guiding principle will point inevitably towards solipsism unless it is limited by other principles or taken with the context of some strong assumptions. I would interpret this as a reductio ad absurdum argument why a worldview must be evaluated on more sophisticated grounds than simply Occam's razor and explanatory power.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

Does Occam's Razor favor metaphysical solipsism?

No. The problem with metaphysical solipsism is it's a poor tool for explaining one's experiences in life which in direct comparison to physicalism, has a robust theory that can explain and predict how the world works. There is more than just parsimony to judge a theory by. It may be a simpler theory insofar as that anyone can understand it (even a child), but it doesn't explain CRISPR editing technology, nor does it explain how airplanes fly. So, a simpler theory isn't always a better theory, because theory is usually used to help a thinker explain, plan, and achieve goals. The primary attraction to solipsism is that entreats the thinker to reflect on metaphysical ideas like fallibilism, radical skepticism, and theory of mind. It often comes as a surprise that direct realism is a presumption, and not a given. Plus, it's a little too close to the Dead Internet Theory to take seriously.
Thus, we are left with the fact that solipsism is incapable of explaining why there appears to be, and why so many people believe there are other minds. It is a diffuse position, therefore, to cite Occam's razor as the backbone of an argument that says, one mind is fewer than 8 billion minds, and I just happen to be that mind, and everything else is mere illusion. Evolution, for instance, gives a meaningful account of biological life and consciousness, but solipsism, not being a meaningful theory of the physical world, has ultimately no justification; it instead relies on some ambiguous notion of radical skepticism about ordinary events and facts we intuit. (Which is why anyone who is a genuine solipsist is likely to be locked up as mentally incapable, and everyone else behaves as if there are other agents who have their own minds.)

This debate may be of interest: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155973/discussion-on-answer-by-syed-does-occams-razor-favor-metaphysical-solipsism

Playing devil's advocate here but there is a tool to explain one's experiences in life: the experiences occur based on the same mathematical laws defined in physics. The only difference is that these laws would operate on objects within consciousness and not objects in an external world. Why is this not possible? And does this not show that there is actually no explanatory advantage in believing in an external world?

@syed You conflate laws and regularities. A law is a description of a regularity; therefore laws don't operate on anything in a physically meaningful way. See reification fallacy.

@JD it doesn’t matter whether laws are descriptions or prescriptions for the purpose of my point. Even if they’re descriptions, they can simply describe the patterns occurring in a solipsistic mental universe, similar to how they describe the patterns occurring in the external world. So in what sense does the external world theory have an advantage?

@Syed Non-solipsism is a simpler explanation for direct realism. There appear to be other minds. What justification is there there are not? You have no adequate justification, therefore you find yourself in a self-refuting position.

This seems mainly to be arguing directly against solipsism, not addressing the actual proposition at issue, that Occam's Razor favors metaphysical solipsism.  It is not inconsistent to reject solipsism yet accept that Occam's Razor favors it.

Occam's razor is a guideline justified by probability theory. If you have an explanation that rests upon n assumptions, and each of those assumptions has some independent probability of being true, then the probability of your explanation being true is the product of all the individual probabilities. It follows trivially that you can increase the probability of your explanation being true, if you can eliminate any one of the assumptions while leaving the probability of the rest unchanged.
Clearly, replacing many high-probability assumptions by fewer low-probability assumptions can lead to a less probable explanation. An explanation based on ten assumptions that are each 90% likely, is thousands of times more probable than an explanation based on a single assumption with a probability of a million to one.
The lesson is that simply reducing the number of assumed entities does not necessarily make for a better explanation- you have to take other factors into account.

How do we evaluate the probability of an assumption?

How do you count assumptions?

@DarkMalthorp and syed you tell me. That's the point. People blindly cite Occam's razor without having stopped to think about when and how it has any validity, and they apply it nonsensically to reach all kinds of silly conclusions.

I do not accept that it is Occam's Razor that your probability theory based argument justifies.  Certainly OR was not conceived as a probabilistic principle, and none of the usual formulations speak to the probability of assumptions being true.  I think you're arguing for a different, likely unnamed principle.  I also think you have not addressed the question actually posed -- does OR favor solipsism -- with respect to any characterization of or variation on OR.

@JohnBollinger I am saying that OR is not meaningful unless it is applied in the spirit I have described. Applied without rigour, OR can be said to favour almost any nonsensical idea provided it superficially seems to have fewer ‘ entities’, whatever that means.

I wholly agree that OR can be, and frequently is misapplied.  I am prepared to entertain the idea that it is not inherently meaningful at all.  Your probabilistic approach to analyzing argumentation is certainly more justifiable in a context where we acknowledge and care about some of our assumptions being uncertain.  But I do not accept that what you are justifying is OR.

@JohnBollinger if I were not a saintly pacifist I would say you are pontificating vacuously. Have a look at the Wikipedia entry for OR. You will find firstly that the principle itself is ill-defined and secondly that my mathematical interpretation of it is one happily shared by others. However, I suspect the point is hardly worth the effort of typing any more about it!

Occam’s razor is a methodological principle to improve the quality of argumentation, independently from the issue of a discussion.
Methodological solipsism is a certain ontological stance from the class of monistic ontological positions.
Occam’s razor applies if two argumentations have the same explanatory power but are distinct in number and quality of their technical terms. The explanatory power of solipsism is questionable.

Occam’s razor applies between theories only if they explain the data equally well. This is not one of those cases.
As an example, the existence of an external world that follows physical laws explains why we experience a particular kind of world rather than another. Without this, the fact that our “experience” follows laws becomes a complete mystery and a brute fact, especially since there is nothing within the act of an immaterial experience that necessitates order.
In other words, solipsism has no explanation for why we experience X instead of Y. The existence of a world combined with the laws that govern it do tell us why we experience X instead of Y. Thus, solipsism is inferior when it comes to explanatory power.
Furthermore, one can use arguments by analogy to infer the existence of other minds. In our experience, we can see other humans that behave and look very similarly to us. This similarity can be used to infer other similarities such as the existence of other minds.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Occam's razor is not about which metaphysical viewpoint is correct or incorrect. It is merely a problem-solving technique about how we organize our searching for explanations. This Wikipedia quote formulates it very nicely: "This philosophical razor advocates that when presented with competing hypotheses about the same prediction and both theories have equal explanatory power one should prefer the hypothesis that requires the fewest assumptions and that this is not meant to be a way of choosing between hypotheses that make different predictions."
Any tool can be misused for something it was never intended to be used. Occam's razor is not about my viewpoint being simpler and making fewer assumptions than yours, therefore it must be more correct than yours. Occam's razor is merely a search tool: if you have an unknown phenomena, you can propose many possible hypotheses, and Occam's razor helps prioritize the order in which you test those hypotheses. But you have to experimentally test them! If evidence does not support the first one, you select the next one to test. This is what Occam's razor is for.

Short answer: No.
We could differentiate metaphysical/ontological simplicity from explanatory simplicity.
Metaphysical simplicity would be the number of entities existing in reality, and it may favour solipsism. But it has issues:

Shouldn't we also consider the simplicity of each of those entities, and how would we measure that?

How do you delineate where one entity ends and another begins (in one sense, the universe is one entity, in another sense, a single person is billions upon billions of entities that are atoms)?

Why is this a useful or meaningful metric that we should use?

This also doesn't seem to consider the chain of causation that gets you to the current state of reality, which seems fairly important.


Explanatory simplicity is arguably more useful, and that's what Occam's razor tends to relate to. This relates to the explanatory power of claims. For this:

We reject claims that don't explain any evidence. This would include things that have no effect on our observable reality.
Let's say claim A can sufficiently* explain 10 pieces of evidence and claim B can explain 2 of those pieces. We accept claim A for all 10 pieces, rather than accepting claim A for 8 pieces and claim B for 2 pieces.
We favour claims with fewer surprising facts. If the claim is that some specific person loves you, it would be surprising if they make you suffer for seemingly no reason.
We favour claims with fewer "just so" facts. If one says that only one's own mind exists, floating in a void somewhere, and this entire reality is a hallucination, this raises the question of why you're experiencing this reality instead of any other. Every part of this reality is "just so".
This framing may still need some refinement, but we favour claims with a smaller "model space". If we compare this reality objectively existing versus us living in a simulation, one might say that the "metaphysical space" (the scope of what exists in reality) is similar. But the model space (the scope of models that exist as part of that claim) is much larger for a simulation, because in both cases you'd have a model that is this reality, but for a simulation you'd also have a model that is the "true" reality.
Related to the points above, we'd reject claims that are interchangeable with other claims without affecting explanatory power much. One might posit that you're a mind floating in a void, or one might posit that you're in a simulation, or one might posit that you're in a simulation inside another simulation, and maybe the simulation was made by a dude named Steve, or maybe his name is Albert. Many of those explain the evidence similarly well across a number of factors, so it would be hard to pick one above the other. But we can also pick none of them, and just say that observed reality is objective reality.

There is a tradeoff between these factors: you could say that hallucination explains all accounts of something and therefore you don't need any other explanations for those accounts (and sometimes that may be most reasonable). But that may create more "just so" facts, where you may not be able to explain why those specific hallucinations happened.
Explanatory simplicity seems to do a good job of leading to reliable beliefs, and we evaluate reliability through correct predictions and coherence.
Solipsism doesn't measure up well by this standard, so we'd reject it.

"Non-solipsism assert just as many if not more "just so" facts as solipsism, you just push them far back in time"?
This is incorrect, or it misunderstands what is meant by "just so" facts.
If you see a horse:
Under solispism, it's because your mind conjured up that horse for some reason, it's "just so".
Under non-solipsism, it would be because the horse is actually there.

You see the horse because light (which originated from some light source, which is there because of some other cause) bounces off of the horse and enters your eye, and that sends signals to your brain for you to "see" the horse.
The horse ended up where it is because of how the environment affected it, and how it acted because of brain activity (which ended up as it is because of evolution).
The horse ended up existing at all and growing up where it did because another horse gave birth to it, and that was caused by a process that should've been explained to you in a "birds and the bees" talk at some point.
Those horses ended up doing that because of how they acted and how they were affected by their environment, and because other horses gave birth to them, which happened because other horses and further back other species acted and gave birth to them.
The environment they exist in is how it is because of weather and climate and the Sun and animals acting on it and so forth.

The more you can say something happened "because" of something else, the less "just so" your explanation is, and there are a lot of "because" statements above.
Of course you can just make up a "because", but that would give it equal explanatory power to other things one can make up, which makes it a poor explanation (as noted above). For all the steps above, they're supported by strong evidence (at least in the general sense, even if not for a specific horse).
The laws of physics and starting state of the universe could be said to be "just so" (for now, at least). But being able to "push just-so facts far back in time" is exactly what makes for a good explanation. We've explained a whole bunch of things up to that point, and explained some things in terms of other things. Meanwhile, solipsism can't offer much beyond "because my brain conjured it up for some reason" for any and all your sensory experiences - everything is "just so" (or it can make up unsupported reasons why those things were conjured up).

On the contrary, non-solipsism assert just as many if not more "just so" facts as solipsism, you just push them far back in time or sweep them to the back end of a long chain of logic so that youre not constantly looking at them. If you would ask a solipsist, "why these hallucinations and not others?", you might just as well ask yourself, "why these physical laws and constants and not others?"

Under Occam's razor, the padding between that fundamental "why?" question and your own experienced reality is a downside, not an advantage.

You didn’t say how solipsism doesn’t measure up well even according to the standards you outlined. First, a hallucination implies a generator of the consciousness. Why assume this? Perhaps the experiences of your mind merely exist. You say that there’s no explanation for why we have a particular experience at a moment rather than another. Let’s add laws to that consciousness then. The laws can be the same as in the same laws in physics except they’re acting on imagined entities rather than real entities. Like a video game from a first person POV without a creator. Is this not simpler?

@ DarkMalthorp Edited to address "non-solipsism assert just as many if not more 'just so' facts as solipsism" (and that also addresses @ Syed's comment).

@DarkMalthorp Is correct. I'll add that solipsism is either people deliberately fooling themselves, or cynical intellectual trolling. It would only be true if I was  God — a possibility I'm not willing to entertain.

@MissUnderstands - there is a third option. Solipsism is a test for your epistemology: Obviously, it is wrong. But how do you know that? That's an interesting question, and many epistemologies I see proposed do not have a good answer.

Solipsism is highly asymmetrical theory and in that sense a much less simpler one. That my experience is analogous to others experiences is highly symmetrical.
